# Render JSON response to django template after ajax call

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I am creating a poll test site which shows the result of the poll and the poll itself in the same page. What I want to do is when a user votes the result will change simultaneously.

This is my code for jquery:

```
<script>
    var result= document.getElementById('result');
    (function poll(){
            $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:8007/api/get_poll/", success: function(data){
                    result.innerHTML = data;
            }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
    })();
</script>
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def get_result(request):
    ...
    # this is what i want to pass
    poll = {'set1': [{'poll': 1, 'votes': 25}, {'poll': 2, 'votes': 20}], 'set2': [{'poll': 1, 'votes': 3}]}

    return JsonResponse(poll)
```

For my template:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Oh, i forgot. silly me. the question is how can i properly extract the data on my template? because my template shows nothing with my current code.

Comment: and the question?

Comment: @e4c5 oops! updated

Comment: can you add the form view and the full template